# Single Response Spreadsheet (with multiple sheets) from multiple forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have four surveys (google forms) from which I want responses to go to a *single* response spreadsheet (each on a different sheet).  It appears in the form view that I can select to have the response go to a new sheet in an existing spreadsheet, but when I select that option on the second form, I get a message saying that the spreadsheet is already in use.  How do I get this feature to work properly?  I want all the pre- and post- survey data in one single spreadsheet!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has changed in new Google Sheets because in the second and subsequent Forms it seems possible to select Responses, `Choose response destination`:

[image: WA41689 first example]

`New sheet in an existing spreadsheet...`, <kbd>Choose</kbd>:

[image: WA41689 second example]

find the Response Sheet for the *first* Form, <kbd>Select</kbd> and for this to work.