# How to post responses from Google forms to a specific sheet in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a form, a Google form, and I'd like to post the user's responses to a specific sheet in the Google spreadsheet. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that responses by different users should go to different sheets? Or that responses by one particular user should to a separate sheet? Or that all responses should to go some sheet other than the one that the form created? Please clarify. Meanwhile, the questions listed [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheets%5D+form+sheet) may already have an answer.

Comment: I meant that all responses should go to one sheet other than the one the form originally created. I took a look at the link provided but did not see a match to my question/issue. Thank you.

Comment: I think I found the answer [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41689/single-response-spreadsheet-with-multiple-sheets-from-multiple-forms?rq=1)

Comment: That answer I linked above helped, although, it still doesn't explain how to put the responses in a specific sheet, the example above would still add the responses to the first sheet created.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Open the form.

Step 2: Click on **"Responses"** from toolbar.

Step 3: Click on **"Change response destination"**.

Step 4: If you want to save responses in existing spreadsheet with a new sheet, choose **"New sheet in an existing spreadsheet"** or if you want to save responses to a new spreadsheet choose **"New Spreadsheet"** and **"Type the name"** for a new spreadsheet.

---

You're done now.

Comment: Question says "I'd like to post user's responses to a specific sheet"... this does not answer how that question, it answers a completely different question, "If you want to save responses in existing spreadsheet with a new sheet".    I don't want to save to a new sheet, I want to save to an existing one!

Comment: @Michael You can also select existing sheet in a spreadsheet by following the same instructions.

Comment: @UmarAhsan Sorry, the terminology "sheet" is somewhat overloaded here, as it both refers to the whole spreadsheet itself, which is what you are indicating, and to individual sheets in the spreadsheet.  When I select an existing spreadsheet it creates a new sheet in that spreadsheet and I'm looking for a way to instead use an already existing sheet in the spreadsheet I select.

Comment: @Michael did you get a solution