# Link Google Form responses To Already Existing Google Spreadsheet Tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form. I had all of my Google Form responses linked to a specific tab in my Google Spreadsheet. Somehow my form responses were unlinked from my tab. When I go to re-link my form responses to my already existing tab it only gives me the option to create a new tab in my spreadsheet.

How do I simply re-link my Google Form responses to my **already existing tab in my Google Spreadsheet?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post responses from Google forms to a specific sheet in a Google spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/79967/how-to-post-responses-from-google-forms-to-a-specific-sheet-in-a-google-spreadsh)

Comment: @serenesat The possible duplicate question while already has an upvoted answer, that answer doesn't answer the question as it includes to send the forms response to a spreadsheet but not to an existing sheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can NOT.
Google will **always** create a new sheet automatically.

But this is not actually an issue. Of course that depends on what your issue is:

**1.** What happens to my old answers?
    *They are copied over to the new sheet automatically.*

**2.** But the sheet has a different name.
    *Just rename it to whatever you like.*

**3.** What about the formulas I had in my old sheet?
    *Just copy those over manually.*

**4.** I had the sheet pushing/pulling data to/from elsewhere.
    *Make manual adjustments so whatever you were doing, points to the new sheet.*

I believe that covers it.
If your issue is not in the above list, let us know.

Comment: Note: This is not useful when the questions on the form changed through time, as responses to deprecated questions are not copied over

Comment: What about if you have a spreadsheet full of responses from a previous questionnaire platform and want to combine them with the google responses?

Comment: I think if you follow the above steps you will be fine. If still facing issues, share a test sheet so you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the existing form and link it there under RESPONSES -- SELECT DESTINATION